# Use pandas dataframe column values to pivot other columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot, pivot-table

I have the following `dataframe` which I want to reshape:

```
  dir  hour  board_sign  pass
   1    5      d          294
   1    5      u          342
   1    6      d          1368
   1    6      u          1268
   1    7      d          3880
   1    7      u          3817
```

What I want to do is to use the values from "board_sign" as new columns which will include the values from "pass" column so that the `dataframe` will look as this:

```
  dir   hour     d     u
  1      5     294    342
  1      6     1368   1268
  1      7     3880   3817
```

I already tried several functions as melt pivot stack and unstack but it seems non of them give the wanted result, I also tried the pivot_table but it make is difficult to iterate since the multi index.

It's seems like an easy operation but I just cant get it right.
Is there any other function I can use for this?

Thanks.

Comment: `df.set_index(['dir','hour','board_sign'])['pass'].unstack()
`

Comment: Also `df.pivot_table(columns='board_sign',index=['dir','hour'],values='pass')`

Comment: thanks!! thats worked exactly as i wanted!

Answer (score 3):

Use `pivot_table`:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=['dir', 'hour'], columns='board_sign', values='pass').reset_index()
del df.columns.name

df
    dir hour    d   u
0   1     5   294   342
1   1     6   1368  1268
2   1     7   3880  3817
```

Comment: i tried the pivot_table option at first and it worked. the problem was that i was difficult to use the output because the mulitiindex in the pivot table.

Comment: with `reset_index()` the multiindex is gone